# Why soft links from standard folders?

Tags: linux, files, python, symlink, hard-link

My observation is, most of the python files sitting in some standard locations like

```
      site-packages
```

are symbolic links to actual file name(sitting in non-standard folder) pointing to inode.

Question

Do you think these should be hard links instead? Because the actual file name change will create issues

Comment: Where do you see that?

Answer (score 0):

You totally misunderstood the idea of links, soft and hard. Soft links work fine when the original and link reside in different filesystems. Hard links work only in one filesystem. Please check [this Q/A in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185899/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link) for more information.